# iOS - Integrating Facebook framework

Tags: ios, facebook

In my iOS app, I successfully integrated latest facebook framework.
Its working fine if "facebook" app is not on my iphone. If the app is not on my iphone, during authentication, its opening the browser and authenticating properly.
But if the facebook app is there on my iphone, after authentication and when returning to my app, its crashing with following error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SBJsonParser errorTrace]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2d9f60'

I have seen the samples provided by facebook and implemented the same in my app. Can some one point out me what might be the issue?

Comment: The issue might be the version of the SBJson Library you have. Check out this similar question: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12301617/application-crash-on-login-in-ios-facebook-sdk-3-0

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a stab in the dark but I think you might be calling the method `errorTrace` on an instance of `SBJsonParser` :)

What's probably happening is you're calling `errorTrace` on something that you have released early. Go through the code path triggered when facebook reopens your app and find a call to `errorTrace`. Set a breakpoint just before it and have a look around to see what's wrong.

Comment: Its been from FB framework. So I cannot put any breakpoint to trace it. Without FB application on my iPhone, its working fine. With facebook app on the device,its crashing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only share something in iOS 6.0 so you use social and account framework and do the job by iPhone internal login using following code

```
-(void)facebook_Share_in_IOS6.0{

    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) //check if Facebook Account is linked
    {
        mySLComposerSheet = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init]; //initiate the Social Controller
        mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]; //Tell him with what social plattform to use it, e.g. facebook or twitter
        [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test",mySLComposerSheet.serviceType]]; //the message you want to post
    //    [mySLComposerSheet addImage:yourimage]; 

        [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Attention" message:@"First Set your facebook account. To post your answer to facebook" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    [mySLComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        NSString *output;
        switch (result) {
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                output = @"Action Cancelled";
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                output = @"Post Successfull";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        } //check if everything worked properly. Give out a message on the state.
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook" message:output delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }];
}
```